# SQL Server Profiler - how do I find which database is being connected?

Tags: database, sql-server-2008-r2, connection, trace, sql-server-profiler

I've Googled this with no success.  I'm using SQL Server Profiler for SQL Server 2008 R2, and I've ensured that for the 'Events Selection' of the trace:

- I'm reporting all columns for Security Audit > Audit Login + Audit Logout
- I'm reporting all columns for Sessions > ExistingConnection

I then start the trace after I've loaded an .aspx page, but just before I carry out an action that calls a certain SQL stored procedure.

I can then see at the start of my trace that under the 'EventClass' column I have 'ExistingConnection', however the 'TextData' for these events doesn't seem to identify the database I'm connecting to - it's telling me the main database settings (e.g. set ansi_padding on).  I can also see that for certain events I can see the 'NTUserName', which gives me some clues.  What I want to find though is which database am I connecting to.  How can I determine this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

When you create a new trace with SQL Server Profiler, a dialog is displayed titled "Trace Properties".

In the lower-right-hand corner you should see a checkbox labeled "Show all columns.  Check it.  Now scroll the table to the left and you should see a checkbox labeled "Database Name".  Check that, and start the trace!

[image: TraceProperties dialog]

Comment: Thanks!  I thought 'Show all columns' would select all of the columns for display in the trace.

Comment: @ChrisHalcrow - Glad to be of help!

Comment: BTW "Show all columns" is in the lower *right* hand corner in SQL Server 2014.

Answer (score 3):

From Trace properties -> Events Selection tab, you can show the Database Column. By default it is not shown.

Answer (score 1):

The Database name for each trace can be found by Events Selection -> (select) Show all columns(bottom right corner) -> (if you are tracing SPs then under Stored Procedure check database name column and check it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07Hbl.png)